# Crystal Reports multiple tables

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am a programmer for many years, but never worked with Crystal Reports before and I could not find the answer on the web. How do I retrieve data in multiple tables when creating the .rpt? For example, I have a dataset with two tables, one with `{person.Id} and {person.name}` and other with {phone.Id} and {phone.number}. There’s one person, but `6 phone numbers`, and they are linked by an `Id`. How can I make one report with the single name and list all `6 numbers`? What is the syntax, or formula? Sorry for my poor English, and thanks. 
Example?

```
John –  44444444
55555555
66666666
77777777
88888888
99999999
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it in two ways.

---

### SQL View

You can either create a `view` in your SQL **database** with both tables to contain all the phone numbers and the person information. You then use that View as the datasource for your report.

---

## DataSet.xsd

You can also create a `DataTable` in your **project solution** by creating a **New Item** > **DataSet**. Your DataSet can contain all the fields necessary such as the person information and their phone numbers, then you assign that DataTable to the designated report as it's datasource.

---

I personally like to use a DataSet and populate my DataTable by code, but that's totally up to you. If you're unclear about what this means, let me know and I'll be able to upload some pictures tomorrow at work (although I'm not sure how your phone number table is setup).